# How to use databinding together with ratingbar's android:progressBackgroundTint attribute?

Tags: android, data-binding, ratingbar, android-databinding

I got the following `RatingBar` and I attempted to use databinding to set its `android:progressBackgroundTint` attribute, but it gives me a compilation error of the following:

> Error:(61, 39) Cannot find the setter for attribute
>   'android:progressBackgroundTint' with parameter type int on
>   android.widget.RatingBar.

```
<RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/item_rating_bar"
        style="@style/StarRatingBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_item_space_title"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@{space.themeColorResourceInt}"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:isIndicator="true"
        android:progressBackgroundTint="@{space.themeColorResourceInt}"
        android:progressTint="@{space.themeColorResourceInt}"
        android:rating="2.5"
        android:secondaryProgressTint="@{space.themeColorResourceInt}"
        tools:rating="2.5"/>
```

`android:progressTint`, `android:backgroundTint` and `android:secondaryProgressTint` are okay to use databinding but not `android:progressBackgroundTint`. May I know how to solve it?

Here is the `getThemeColorResourceInt()` of my `Space` class:

```
...

@Nullable
@Bindable
public int getThemeColorResourceInt() {
    // lazy instiantate
    if (themeColorResourceInt > -1) {
        return themeColorResourceInt;
    }

    if (themeColor != null) {
        themeColorResourceInt = Color.parseColor(themeColor);
        return themeColorResourceInt;
    }

    if (spaceId > -1) {
        try {
            String floorSpaceThemeColor = SpaceBean.getInstance().getCurrentFloor().getSpaceWithSpaceId(spaceId).getThemeColor();
            themeColorResourceInt = Color.parseColor(floorSpaceThemeColor);
            return themeColorResourceInt;
        } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Logger.getLogger().e(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }

    return MainApplication.sContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.btn_brown);
}
...
```

Comment: could you give your space class here!

Comment: the Space class is too large, I just cap a section of that here.

Comment: Shouldn't the color Resource be a hexadecimal String? As the xml attributes accept hexadecimal strings.